# How do I open my web app links by deeplinking?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have converted my website into app and I use [https://app.sarkaribank.com][1] type of links to load in webview. I want to use deep linking. Below is my manifest.xml file.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.sarkaribank.Activities.BottomActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter android:label="SarkariBank">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="app.sarkaribank.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/*.*"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want that my app should open whenever someone clicks any of these kinds of link

https://app.mysitename.com

Comment: show your code for the activity which you want to receive this url.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? Does the code work?

Comment: this code doesn't work obivously

Comment: @KaranKhurana , you can find the BottomActivity here https://github.com/shahishasank/sarkaribankFile

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="app.sarkaribank.com"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="app.sarkaribank.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. And one more question, let's suppose I want to open mysite.com/my-page(works in web browser) in my app, but when i load this url directly it sends me 404 error. But when I use mysite.com/my-page.html, it works perfectly. Please help

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow you to paste a web url and trigger the deeplink at the same time.

Comment: Let me explain again, app.mysite.com/my-page.php works perfect in app. If I open same page in web browser, my url will be mysite.com/my-page (without file extension ). And when I open app.mysite.com/my-page in app it gives 404 error.What I want is path prefix of link should be same in web and app. How do I do it?